# Certains cas où la négation grammaticale ne suit pas la logique?

Tags: grammaire, négation, auxiliaires

La phrase « *Tu dois faire ça* » exprime le devoir de faire quelque chose. Pour exprimer le cas où ce devoir n'existe pas, il faut utiliser un verbe différent :

> Tu n'es pas obligé (ou tenu, forcé, …) de faire ça. *(1)*

On peut aussi considérer les négations grammaticales directes :

> Tu ne dois pas faire ça. *(2)*
>   Tu dois ne pas faire ça. *(3)*

Et il me semble avoir entendu les deux avec une différence très subtile, mais en aucun cas elles ne seraient comprises comme *(1)*. Elles seraient toutes deux comprises comme une interdiction.

La tournure *(3)* est très rarement utilisée et son sens n'est pas ambigu (l'obligation de ne pas faire est une interdiction). Par contre, en regardant bien, la phrase *(2)* suit exactement la même construction que *(1)*, et ces deux phrases devraient donc avoir un sens similaire (la « non-obligation » de faire). En pratique *(2)* est comprise comme *(3)*, utilisée à la place de *(3)*, et a un sens très différent de *(1)*.

Constatation : la négation grammaticale du verbe *devoir* ne produit pas sa négation sémantique.
Est-ce le seul cas où ce phénomène étrange apparaît en français ?

Est-ce que ce phénomène a un nom ?

*Remarque :* en anglais *must* a la même maladie que *devoir*, mais *müssen* ne l'a pas en allemand.

Comment: Je pense qu'il faut distinguer : la non-obligation de faire; l'obligation de "non-faire" (de faire le contraire, en somme); et l'interdiction de faire.

Comment: Peut-être c'est grâce à l'influence de la langue parlée, parce que quand on ne dit pas le « ne », on ne peut pas faire la difference entre votre (2) et (3). (Mais ça n'explique pas la même phénomène avec « il faut que ».)

Comment: La (2) peut parfois être comprise comme "tu n'es pas obligé" il me semble, mais je suis d'accord que ce n'est pas ce qu'on comprend en premier. Par exemple : "Je dois me coucher avant minuit ?" "Mais non tu ne dois pas te coucher avant minuit, c'est les vacances".

Answer (score 7):

Réponse partielle à ma propre question… Je me rends compte que le même phénomène apparaît pour d'autres verbes modaux (mais pas tous).

Il y a très peu de différence entre ces variantes pour *penser* et *croire* :

> Je ne pense pas y arriver.
> Je pense ne pas y arriver.
>
> Je ne crois pas pouvoir y arriver.
> Je crois ne pas pouvoir y arriver.

ou pour *falloir* :

> Il ne faut pas que cela se sache.
> Il faut que cela ne se sache pas.

La négation peut « glisser » sans que cela corresponde à une réelle négation de l'auxiliaire.

Par contre déplacer la négation pour *pouvoir* a une véritable influence. Les deux phrases qui suivent ont vraiment des sens distincts :

> Je ne pourrais pas y arriver.
> Je pourrais ne pas y arriver.

Answer (score 5):

Précisons que ta forme (3) est la *forme orale familière dans la vaste majorité de la francophonie*. La chute du *ne* dans les négations est un phénomène extrêmement répandu du langage parlé, et est probablement la seule raison qui permette l'existence même de la négation multiple (« J'ai pas vu personne »).

Quant à la distinction subtile entre (1) et (2), je dirais que la construction exprime encore un négatif, mais ce négatif *s'applique généralement à l'objet*, et non à l'existence d'un devoir lui-même (Ce sens est au TLFi : [II.A.1.b)γ](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devoir))! Le fait étant que dans une construction de ce genre, il faut allonger la phrase pour préciser que la négation s'applique à un quasi auxiliaire et non au verbe auxiliaire (un infinitif ne peut recevoir la négation de manière explicite ici : on aboutit à quelque chose comme « tu dois ne pas faire ça »), et que le sens le plus commun peut donc varier. Comparons avec *finir* :

> Je ne finis pas de manger, je finis de cuisiner.
>   Je ne finis pas de manger, je commence.

En contraste, un auxiliaire de la forme *Je suis X de* n'a pas ce problème, et on peut alors opposer les deux formulations suivantes (même si la seconde est plus inhabituelle, elle n'élicite pas la même réaction que l'impossible *tu dois ne pas faire ça*) :

> Je ne suis pas forcé de manger.
>   Je suis forcé de ne pas manger.

Comment: Le *ne* est encore présent dans *(3)*, et de toute façon à l'écrit ce serait *(2)* qui serait choisi pour l'expression familière « Tu dois pas faire ça. ». Ensuite, dans le français tel qu'il est utilisé, la différence entre *(1)* et *(2)* n'est *pas* subtile mais radicale (où alors on ne parle pas la même langue…). La négation de *faire* est *ne pas faire*. Et à propos du commentaire de la fin, je pense que l'effet de style qui consiste a reprendre une erreur dans une phrase précédente en la tournant négativement n'a rien à voir avec la particularité de *devoir*.

Comment: Mais on ne peux pas dire "ne pas faire" dès lors qu'un auxiliaire est impliqué: c'est pour ça qu'on écrit "je n'ai pas fait"! L'effet de style en question sert à faire ressortir que cette ambigüité est impossible à clarifier sans tourner la phrase différemment. L'exemple se traduit avec devoir: «Je ne dois pas manger, je dois chanter.» s'oppose à «Je ne dois pas chanter, je ne peux pas chanter.» Que le premier sens reflète une interdiction en l'absence d'information supplémentaire n'a rien de surprenant.

Comment: Intéressant, dans « Je ne dois pas manger, je dois chanter » la véritable négation apparaît, mais on ne s'en rend compte qu'en lisant la deuxième partie de la phrase!

Comment: Il me semble que la négation dans la phrase « Je ne dois pas manger, je dois chanter » représente ce qui s'appelle *la négation métalinguistique*, et qu'elle a peu à voir avec la question de « ne pas devoir ». On peut se servir de ce genre de négation même quand la proposition sera vrai sans aucune négation ; [Wikipédia fournit plusieurs tels exemples](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_%28linguistique%29#N.C3.A9gation_non_v.C3.A9riconditionelle).

Comment: @Circeus: downvote en retard, mais ta réponse contient plein de petites erreurs peut-être involontaires qui mériteraient d'être corrigées.

Answer (score 4):

J'apporte une contribution aux tentatives de réponse au sujet "Certains cas où la négation grammaticale ne suit pas la logique ?".

On distingue entre négation grammaticale et négation logique, notamment parce que une négation grammaticale n'exprime pas toujours une négation logique. En effet, la négation grammaticale d'un énoncé a pour fonction d'exprimer le contraire de l'énoncé à nier, tandis que la négation logique a pour fonction d'inverser la valeur de vérité de l'énoncé. C'est que la négation logique est précisément l'une des opérations de la logique (logique des propositions, logique des prédicats, etc.).

Soit p une proposition quelconque qui, en admettant le principe de bivalence, peut être ou bien vraie ou bien fausse (pas les deux à la fois). On a donc :
-si p est vraie, alors non-p est fausses ;
-si p est fausse, alors non-p est vraie ;
-si non-p est vraie, alors p est fausse ;
-si non-p est fausse, alors p est vraie.
Alors que :
-si p est vraie, alors p vraie ;
-si p est fausse, alors p est fausse ;
-si non-p est vraie, alors non-p est vraie ;
-si non-p est fausse, alors non-p est fausse. 
On voit bien que la négation logique inverse la valeur de vérité.

Quelques exemples :

1. Certains philosophes sont musiciens.
2. Certains philosophes ne sont pas musiciens.

"2." est la négation grammaticale de "1.", mais pas sa négation logique, puisque "2." n'inverse pas la valeur de vérité de "1.". "1." et "2." sont toutes les deux vraies. Si "2." était la négation logique de "1.", "2." serait fausse...

3. Tous les philosophes sont musiciens.
4. Aucun philosophe n'est musicien.

"4." n'est pas la négation logique de "3.", parce que "4." n'inverse pas la valeur de vérité de "3.". "3." et "4." sont toutes les deux fausses. Si "4." était la négation logique de "3.", "4." serait vraie...

Et voici un exemple spécial :

1. Tu dois voler.
2. Tu ne dois pas voler.

"2." est la négation grammaticale de "1.", mais elle n'est pas sa négation logique. Si tel est le cas, c'est parce que la négation logique n'a aucun effet sur les énoncés qui ne sont pas déclaratifs. Seuls les énoncés déclaratifs sont, en logique, susceptibles d'avoir une valeur de vérité (le vrai ou le faux). En effet, si "1." ne peut pas avoir une valeur de vérité, alors "2." ne peut en aucun cas avoir la valeur de vérité inverse...

Comment: J'aime l'exemple avec « certains ».