# Le contraire de « il faut que »

Tags: négation

Si je dis :

> Il ne faut pas que tu manges.

Je pense que ça peut vouloir dire deux choses (mais je ne suis pas sûr) :

1. Tu peux manger si tu veux, mais tu n'as pas besoin de manger.
2. Tu ne dois pas manger.

Quelle est l'interprétation la plus courante ? C'est pas possible de faire une distinction avec le verbe falloir ? J'aurais pensé qu'on disait :

> Il faut que tu ne manges pas.

pour dire (2) et que la première phrase était réservée pour (1), mais je pense avoir entendu que ce n'est pas vrai.

Comment: Une question qui répond à une autre http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/certains-cas-ou-la-negation-grammaticale-ne-suit-pas-la-logique :-)

Comment: C'est très drôle !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'interprétation la plus commune pour *Il ne faut pas que tu manges* est :

> Tu ne dois pas manger.

ou

> Il est important que tu ne manges pas.

Pour dire « Tu peux manger si tu veux, mais tu n'as pas besoin de manger », on emploierait plutôt la formulation :

> Tu n'as pas à manger.

(Même si cette formulation pourrait aussi dire *Tu n'as rien à manger*.)

Answer (score 5):

L’interprétation la plus courante est à mon avis la 2.

Pour dire 1, il faudrait plutôt utiliser "devoir":

> Tu ne devrais pas manger

Comment: Ce n'est pas seulement « la plus courante », c'est la seule.

Answer (score 2):

"Il faut que tu manges" "It is necessary that you eat..." has TWO possible opposites.

The first is: Il NE faut que tu manges. "It is NOT necessary that you eat."

The second is: Il faut que tu NE manges PAS. "It is necessary that you NOT eat."

It all depends on whether you negate the "faut" or "manges."

Answer (score 2):

« Il ne faut pas que tu manges » ou « tu ne dois pas manger » signifient « il est nécessaire que tu ne manges pas. »

Pour exprimer la négation de « il faut que tu manges », on peut soit utiliser le verbe *pouvoir*, soit exprimer la modalité autrement que par un verbe. Par exemple :

> Tu peux ne pas manger.
>   Tu n'est pas obligé de manger.
>   Il n'est pas nécessaire que tu manges.

« Il faut que tu ne manges pas » est synonyme (moins courant) de « il ne faut pas que tu manges », et renforce l'interdiction. Si « il ne faut pas que tu manges » signifie « il est important que tu ne manges pas », « il faut que tu ne manges pas » signifie « il est très important que tu ne manges pas ».

Answer (score 2):

« Il ne faut pas que tu manges » veut toujours dire qu’il est défendu de manger au sujet.

Si tu cherches à exprimer l’absence de contrainte, tu peux dire :

> Tu n’es pas tenu de manger.

Mais sinon, le verbe falloir implique nécessairement une injonction. Tu peux certes l’utiliser pour exprimer au sujet qu’il n’est pas obligé de manger en lui enjoignant de ne pas se sentir ainsi !

> Il ne faut pas que tu te sentes obligé de manger.
>   Mais alors c’est une injonction à la non-injonction XD