# L'usage de « il ne faut pas » pour l'interdiction

Tags: étymologie, négation, double-négation

J'avais toujours cette question dans l'esprit mais je me disais souvent que peut-être c'était juste une faute isolée ou que je ne comprenais pas assez le français mais maintenant je vais la poser au FSE même si elle rappellerait un peu un sketch de R.Devos.

En français il est fréquent d'utiliser la formule "**il ne faut pas" + infinitif** pour exprimer une interdiction mais cette formule est - en quelque sorte - le sujet d'une ambiguité ;

Je ne suis pas français et personnellement j'entends par l'expression "*il ne faut pas*" que la négation porte sur le degré d'obligation (c'est-à-dire sur "*s'il fallait ou non*") ainsi le sujet en question a le choix entre faire et ne pas faire l'action en question, alors que l'emploi français courant est une injonction d’éviter systématiquement (défense) cette action dans le contexte d'une négation totale.

Pour comparer avec d'autres langues comme l'arabe ou l'anglais, c'est différent: par exemple en anglais on utilise "*should not*" ou "*ought not*" pour l'interdiction alors que "*don't have to*" revient explicitement à dire qu'il n'y a pas d'obligation ("*you are free to ... or to not*").

En termes de logique, cela pourrait être exprimer par des ensembles, autrement dit des relations du type inclusion-exclusion (un peu difficile à representer) mais aussi par des propositions (moins fidèle au concept mais plus facile à representer) :

> soit A l'action du verbe à l'infinitif et T l'obligation portée par "falloir"

partant du cas affirmatif qui serait

> T ∧ A (il faut faire A cad A est obligatoire)

et comme non français, j'entends par l'emploi de "il ne faut pas" la négation partielle

> (¬T) ∧ A  ( cad A n'est pas obligatoire)

alors que l'usage français commun (sujet de ma question) équivaut à

> T ∧ (¬A)  (cad A est interdit)

Alors est-ce que cet usage est formel, autrement dit est-ce que l'académie française reconnaît cet usage (ou non) et le cas échéant qu'en serait l'origine ?

EDIT : j'ai trouvé une question similaire [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8712/le-contraire-de-il-faut-que) mais dans celle-ci on est plutôt concerné par les origines du glissement de sens

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien la question. Est-ce que tu demandes si l'expression `il ne faut pas` désigne une interdiction formelle ou une absence d'obligation?

Comment: Je pense que cette question se rapproche, sans être stricto-sensu identique, de [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/certains-cas-o%C3%B9-la-n%C3%A9gation-grammaticale-ne-suit-pas-la-logique)

Comment: ma question est à propos de la consécration d'un usage qui me semble incorrect et son etymologie

Comment: @Aweuzegaga,je porte l'attention sur un certain déplacment du focus de la négation dans ce genre de structures cad ce qui est déstiné à exprimer une interdiction formelle pourrait être d'une façon equivoque s'interpreter par une absence d'obligation - comment on est arrivé là ?

Comment: ma question est à propos des causes de ce glissement de sens

Comment: Fichtre.Qu'elle élucubration pour adresser une question qui en définitive semble fort simple... Tu gagnerais en clarté à ne pas essayer de faire des phrases alambiquées pour rien. Ma question n'attendait qu'un **oui c'est ça** ou **non, ça n'est pas que ça. Je veux savoir d'où vient le glissement de sens si tant est qu'il y en ait un**. Pas un _focus d'une structure avec une interprétation équivoque de_. Bref. Pour répondre simplement donc : non, **`il ne faut pas` + infinitif** ne signifie pas une absence d'obligation. Il s'agit d'une interdiction formelle. Il n'y a pas de glissement de sens.

Comment: Il n'est pas requis, on n'a pas besoin de...

Answer (score 1):

Je vois ce que tu veux dire, en terme de logique pur c'est correct mais non, "*il ne faut pas*" **ne peut pas** avoir le sens de "*il n'est pas obligatoire de*".

Pourtant, on pourrait faire la distinction entre "*il ne faut pas [verbe]*" et "*il faut ne pas [action]*", mais ce dernier n'est jamais utilisé et le premier a toujours le sens de l'interdiction.

Par contre je ne suis pas d'accord avec le fait que l'anglais soit différent, la négation de l'obligation ou du conseil (*musn't* et *shouldn't* par exemple) fonctionne de la même façon.

J'imagine que selon toi, "*You must not run*" est interprété comme :

> "*You must (not run)*

et pas comme :

> "*You (must not) run*"

Et que la négation est donc appliquée au verbe et non à l'auxiliaire, mais c'est très disctuable. Pour moi la contraction et le fait qu'on puisse utiliser l'auxiliaire et la négation seuls ("*You shouldn't!*") indiquent fortement que la négation s'applique à l'auxiliaire. Ou peut-être tu parlais seulement de "*have to/ don't have to*" ?

Comment: Peut-être est-ce un belgicisme, mais "Il ne faut pas manger de pommes" peut chez nous être interprété comme "Il n'y a aucune obligation de manger des pommes", même si "Il est interdit de manger des pommes" est le sens le plus courant. Généralement pour lever toute ambiguïté on utilise un adverbe : "Il ne faut pas absolument/nécessairemement/obligatoirement/.... manger de pommes."

Comment: C'est une expression figée ou ça marche pour tout ?

Comment: Oups je me rends compte de l'ambiguïté de mon commentaire. Cela marche "pour tout", donc pas exclusivement avec manger et encore moins exclusivement avec des pommes...

Answer (score 1):

Vos représentations du problème par des symboles de la logique mathématique sont erronées ; il n'est absolument pas question d'une *conjonction* de « falloir » avec un verbe à l'infinitif. De plus, un verbe à l'infinitif ne peut en aucun cas être une proposition ; de sorte qu'un assemblage de mots puisse être considéré comme étant une proposition dans un calcul il est nécessaire que l'on sache qu'une *valeur de vérité* peut être attachée à l'assemblage, c'est à dire que l'on sache qu'il est possible de dire si la proposition est soit *vraie* soit *fausse* ; si on n'a qu'un verbe à l'infinitif (« parler » par exemple), on ne peut pas dire de cela que ça peut être vrai ou faux : ça n'a pas de valeur de vérité.

La phrase « Jean parlait à Pierre hier soir. » est une proposition (du point de vue mathématique) parce que l'on peut décider si c'est vrai ou faux.

Le symbole de négation logique, en tant que connecteur logique se traduit par l'introduction de la négation *grammaticale* dans la proposition, mais ce n'est pas cette négation ;

Vous pouvez écrire ceci, symboliquement ;

> ¬(Jean parlait à Pierre hier soir.) <===> Jean **ne** parlait **pas** à Pierre hier soir.

Ceci n'a pas de sens en logique ;

> Jean ¬(parlait) à Pierre hier soir. <===> Jean **ne** parlait **pas** à Pierre hier soir.

En prenant un verbe, « parler », ce que vous expliquez revient à ceci, en marquant les étapes au moyen de votre symbolisme en erreur mais qui correspond à un état de choses exact;

- (T ∧ A)__ Il faut parler. *Vous comprenez « Il faut » comme l'expression d'une  nécessité, ici celle de parler.*
- (¬T) ∧ A__ Il ne faut pas parler. *Vous comprenez « Il ne faut pas » comme l'expression d'un manque de nécessité, ici celle de parler. Cela revient à dire qu'il n'y a pas une nécessité de parler et donc que l'on peut parler ou ne pas parler. C'est une erreur, mais elle est logique.* Le même problème existe dans le contexte d'une tournure personnelle avec « devoir » : « Vous ne devez pas parler. ». La négation grammaticale de « falloir »  n'existe pas vraiment. Ces verbe modaux correspondent à l'anglais « must » ; la différence est qu'en anglais il n'y a pas de particule explétive, laquelle, en français, donne l'impression que la négation porte sur « falloir ». Il faut considérer dans ce cas que la négation porte sur le verbe à l'infinitif. Remarquez qu'en anglais on n'utilise pas l'auxiliaire de négation, « do », et l'on dit « You must not speak. ». D'ailleurs, en Français, il est correct de dire « Il faut ne pas parler. » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+faut+ne+pas&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20faut%20ne%20pas%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20faut%20ne%20pas%3B%2Cc0)). C'est la seule façon de comprendre cette négation. Un verbe à l'infinitif se construit sans problème avec une négation ;

> Ne pas parler est parfois difficile.

- T ∧ (¬A)__ La présente interprétation est donc la seule possible.

Comment: j'avoue que ma representation logique n'est pas parfaite et j'ai mentionné le fait que ça searait mieux avec des ensembles mais c'est juste pour expliquer mon point de vue