# Quelle différence entre « ne pas conseiller » et « conseiller de ne pas » ?

Tags: négation

Dans un roman j'ai vu :

> Je ne vous conseille pas de me déranger.

Quelle est la différence avec la phrase suivante ?

> Je vous conseIlle de ne pas me déranger.

Comment: Ça me rappelle cette question. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/certains-cas-o%c3%b9-la-n%c3%a9gation-grammaticale-ne-suit-pas-la-logique. Mais dans ce cas c'est plus vraisemblablement un euphémisme.

Comment: Ce n'est pas faux. Mais alors plus une litote qu'un euphémisme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La première forme n'est rien d'autre qu'une **paraphrase** de la seconde.
On trouvera la même nuance qu'entre "*not to advise to*" et "*to advise not to*".
La première forme fait apparaitre une négation plus **directe** que la seconde, d'où l'impression de "menace" évoquée ici par Ty Kayn.
Mais il ne s'agit là que d'impression personnelle.

Answer (score 2):

la première phrase est une menace plus subtile que la deuxième, qui suggère plus fortement qu'il y aura des représailles.